# is there a set greater than the set of real numbers?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I think about complex numbers but $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}^2$ 
and $\mathbb{R}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ !!

Is it true that there is no infinite set $A$ s.t $|A|>|R|$?

Comment: The set of all sets of real numbers is "greater" than the set of all real numbers. In general, given any set $X$, the set of all subsets of $X$ is "greater" than $X$.

Comment: did you mean the power set of real numbers is greater than R itself?

Comment: Yes. This is [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: Maybe you will be interested in [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem).

Comment: Yes, the power set is always greater. But there are also many other. For instance the functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, it is written $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: We should be clear about a few things... First off $\Bbb C\neq \Bbb R^2$ in the traditional sense though there is a clear bijection between them.  Secondly, $\Bbb R^2\not\subseteq \Bbb R^n$.  You have $\Bbb R^2$ is the set of all *pairs* of real numbers while $\Bbb R^n$ is the set of all $n$-tuples of real numbers.  There exists no $n$-tuple which is also a pair (*for $n\neq 2$ of course*).  What you mean to say is that there is a natural injection of $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R^n$, e.g. $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0,0,0,\dots,0)$

Answer (score 3):

You need to be more careful with your sets.

As we can easily find elements in $\mathbb C$ that are not in $\mathbb R^2$ (e.g. $i$) and vice versa (e.g. $(0,1)$), the sets are obviously not identical,so $\mathbb C=\mathbb R^2$ is wrong. Also as $(1,2)\in\mathbb R^2$ and $(1,2)\notin\mathbb R^n$, they are obviously not subsets of each other.

In cases like these where there are very well known bijections/injections, it probably won't cause any problems, but just because you can see a bijection/injection doesn't mean others can (or find it natural in any way), so in general it's very bad practice.

Back to the question: Given a set $A$, [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) tells us the powerset $\mathcal P(A)$ is always larger, specifically we get that $|\mathcal P(\mathbb R)| > |\mathbb R|$.